# Unable to create new user using Azure Active Directory B2C Graph API with chinese character Json data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a user using AAD B2C graph API. It is working fine when the Payload Json is English Character, but If I create the Json Payload with a Chinese character, Its fails.

Json Payload:

```
    {
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Abc1234@#",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "林",
  "mailNickname": "林",
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

**Error Details:**

> "Message": "One or more errors occurred. (Error Calling the Graph
>   API: \n{\r\n  \"odata.error\": {\r\n    \"code\":
>   \"Request_BadRequest\",\r\n    \"message\": {\r\n      \"lang\":
>   \"en\",\r\n      \"value\": \"Invalid value specified for property
>   'mailNickname' of resource 'User'.\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"requestId\":
>   \"b2d0d3bf-394d-4ebd-a5b5-d905f1809c19\",\r\n    \"date\":
>   \"2019-02-15T06:55:06\",\r\n    \"values\": [\r\n      {\r\n
>   \"item\": \"PropertyName\",\r\n        \"value\": \"mailNickname\"\r\n
>   },\r\n      {\r\n        \"item\": \"PropertyErrorCode\",\r\n
>   \"value\": \"InvalidValue\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n})"

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the mailNickname as specified by the error:

```
{
  "givenName": "会话",
  "surname": "宋",
  "mail": "abc@gmail.com",
  "city": "TestCity",
  "state": "hebei",
  "country": "china",
  "postalCode": "1245",
  "mobilePhone": "12345678",
  "mailNickname": "abc",
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayname-here",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "PasswordHere",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": true
  },
  "userPrincipalName": "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

I've also included the other properties the documentation mentions are required.

You can see the reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#create-a-user-work-or-school-account--

Comment: My Final Json fomat is 
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Abc1234@#",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "林",
  "mailNickname": "林",
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}

Comment: Thanks Its working now. 
After Changing the mail name property as "abc" (Extract from email ID abc@gmail.com)